# how to insert value in searchbox after ajax search

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

so i have created an ajax search using jquery and php but there is one problem going on i want to insert the value of searched item in my search box how to do it my code for input type text goes like this

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your country name" id="search">
```

and my code for jquery and php goes like this

```
$('#search').keyup(function()
{
    var searchterm=$(this).val();
    $.post('city.php',{searchterm: searchterm},function(data)
        {
         $('#citysearch').html(data);
        }); 
});
```

and my php code is this

```
if(isset($_POST['searchterm']))
{
    $connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','*****','*********','register');
    $country=$_POST['searchterm'];
    if(!empty($city))
    {
        $query="select countryname from countryname where countryname like '$country%'";
        $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $countryname=$row['countryname'];
            echo $countryname.'<hr>';
        }
    }
}
```

now lets say i have typed 'in' in the search box it gives me two values india and indonesia but how do i select one of them and than insert its value in my searchbox

Comment: There is `autocomplete` plugin. you can use that. why do you want to re-invent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ask to make autocomplete like in gmail

you can use jquery auto complete so there is a good tutorial for it [here](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete)

you can read this article too [here](http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/03/35-best-ajax-jquery-autocomplete-tutorial-plugin-with-examples/)

If You mean that you want to just show one country

simply in the last of sql query add `LIMIT 1` :)